# Wordpress - Mysql Query in page with edit and delete

Tags: wordpress

My code in header :

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
      $userlogin = $user_info->user_login;
?>
```

I want do that in the wordpress page and the user can edit the rows and delete and save

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE user_login LIKE '$userlogin'
```

I am using **[wpDataTable](http://codecanyon.net/item/wpdatatables-responsive-tables-in-wordpress/3958969)** but not working with '$userlogin'

Thanks